# Unable to access page ashx

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, iis, ashx

I have to test a Web Service with visual studio 2015, using IIS.

I have a project "MyWebService", this project contains a page "myPage.ashx". When I start the project my chrome explorer starts on page `localhost - /`. There I can see all file in the project.

But when I click on `myPage.ashx` I got an error 404 :

> HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

I changed the property "browse to URL" to `~/myPage.ashx` but there is no difference. I'm very new to web services and I need help to know where I have to looking for.

Comment: ashx files are not pages but a HTTP handler see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx

Comment: I don't understand how it works. I have another project trying to use `myPage.ashx` with arguments (`http://localhost:52581/myPage.ashx?id=42`) but I have an error 404. I'm trying to debug the webService but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

`.ashx` file extension might not be defined in your IIS.

See official documentation on Microsoft site [How to: Configure an HTTP Handler Extension in IIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx).

Comment: I've tried this way but I don't know how IIS works. I started IIS manager, but unlike documentations, I didn't see my application in the default web site. Actually I just start my web services with visual studio debugger.

Comment: Then maybe you should start with configuring your site in IIS, I'm sure you will find plenty of links in your favourite websearch engine